# Can I use Eclipse and GlassFish together?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I use Eclipse as IDE. I use Eclipse to test my Java apps.

But now I want to make website with Spring, Hibernate. Can I do it through Eclipse only or I need to install GlassFish.

After installing GlassFish can I see some button on Eclipse which put required files automatically in required folders, I mean I don't want to manually copy the files in diff directories.

Do I add Spring, Hibernate in Eclipse or GlassFish?

Something like click on create web app.

Comment: You can download a glassfish plugin for eclipse http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-java-ee-application-server-plugin-eclipse which you can use to deploy your code to the app-server without having to package it to a WAR file each time and manually deploy it, I have not dealt with spring and hibernate yet but I am also a little uncertain of whether this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, which includes GlassFish tools. You can get it from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Alternative, if you have Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, got to Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Add. Then click on "Download additional server adapters. That will show you a list of server adapters that Eclipse knows about, including GF Tools from OEPE. The wizard will guide you through the process of installing it.

Beyond that, if you need help using Java EE facilities of Eclipse, google "Eclipse WTP tutorial" or similar. There are many articles written on the topic.

Comment: The easiest and safest way to get the Enterprise Pack for Eclipse JEE 3.6.1 is through the Eclipse Marketplace found in the Help menu.

Comment: The marketplace client is a good way to go as well. Ultimately the download link, the marketplace client and "download additional server adapters" all point to the same place on Oracle servers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't require Glassfish. You can use any Java web-app container like Jetty, Tomcat, Weblogic etc. Tomcat is the easiest to integrate with Eclipse.

I have used Glassfish previously, but much like stand-alone. I have never integrated Glassfish with Eclipse, but it seems like as easy as Tomcat integration. See here.

http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/

and

here

http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/GF-Tools-for-Eclipse-Guide12.pdf

As quoted in the guide

> **To publish Projects**
>
> To publish applications to the GlassFish Server, use the following procedure:
>
> 1. Select Servers view.
> 2. Select GlassFish Server.
> 3. Right click and select Publish fromServer popup menu.
>      The selected applications are published to the GlassFish Server.

Comment: You would believe from the documentation that it would be as easy to use glassfish in eclipse with the adapter as it is to use tomcat, but it's not.  I had difficulty re-deploying to glassfish in eclipse.  I ended up using netbeans when I was working on the webapp, and eclipse when I was only working on anything else.

Comment: i have downloaded that but how can i confgure eclipse for spring , hibernate